# Where can I find the javascript core library?

Tags: javascript

I know browsers all have their own implementation, but where is the spec, what are the common parts, ie. Array, String, Infinity, etc.

Essentially, I was trying to figure out which variables/parts are available to a browser: location, navigator, window, document, etc, and came to this question

Comment: Every browser follows some version of EcmaScript spec. Look that up.

Comment: @madfriend: once upon a time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but where is the spec, what are the common parts, ie. Array, String, Infinity, etc

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

> Essentially, I was trying to figure out which variables/parts are available to a browser: location, navigator, window, document, etc, and came to this question

Those are not part of JavaScript. Some are defined by the [W3C DOM specifications](http://w3.org/DOM/DOMTR), others are part of the [non-standard DOM 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Template:DOM0) which is best referenced (IMO) via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: +1 for Mozilla Developer Network (MDN), They have compiled super-comprehensive docs on real-world javascript (and css and html etc) use. Here is both their JavaScript Landing page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript and their reference index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference